# ORA-14288 when setting default attributes on an index partition

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle10g, database-partitioning

I need to change the tablespace where 7 indexes are created.  This is a 3TB partitioned index.  A new partition is created each day and then folded into months.  The command I am running is

```
alter index myindex1 modify default attributes for partition
mypartition tablespace myNewIndexTablespace;
```

The error is

> ORA-14288 index is not partitioned by composite range method Cause:
>   The index in a partition or subpartition maintenance operation command
>   must be partitioned by composite range method.

I am trying to figure out the best approach here considering these indexes are big and reside on 52 partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this means that you cannot define a default tablespace for an index partition if that partition does not contain subpartitions.

The reason for that would be that the default tablespace for an object is the one to which new partitions or subpartitions would be assigned on creation. If a table or index is not partitioned then of course it could not have a default tablespace for new partitions, and if a table or index partition is not subpartitioned then it cannot have a default tablespace for the addition of new subpartitions.

You probably want to:

```
alter index
  myindex1
modify
  default attributes
    tablespace myNewIndexTablespace;
```

... and then rebuild the current index partitions to the new tablespace.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_1010.htm#i2129868